# Autocad angle customization

Tags: autocad

I am new in AutoCAD and I try to do a figure but I don't know why my autocad don't work.
This is what I try to do [--> Here <--](https://s1.postimg.org/1worighadr/paint.jpg).

But even if my paint look the good angle [Screenshot_1 - there write 54.6<47.18)](https://postimg.org/gallery/1dczt7mvw/) when I press enter my AutoCAD draws the line like that: Screenshot_2 (from above link)

Any suggestions to "repair" this settings or to enable/disable the option that make this happends.
Sorry for every language mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`56.5685<45` specifies absolute polar coordinates (from UCS origin)
`@56.5685<45` specifies relative polar coordinates (from last point) see [here](http://help.autodesk.com/view/ACD/2017/ENU/?guid=GUID-58C1D97C-A9B3-4C3C-AC1B-95BE3DF2EDB9).

Answer (score 0):

When You Want to Make a Angle in AutoCAD in the Command Line for Eg. Say
Command: L
LINE
Specify first point:
Specify next point or [Close/Undo]: @250<35

Here "@250" is the Length of the Line & "<35" angle in which the Line is Needed.
This is what you have to do..